# How to fetch posts that are commented on last 24 hours only in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fetch all the posts that are commented on last 24 hours range.
What I have tried is:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT comment_post_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_date > '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hours')) . "'", OBJECT );
```

But from above query I am getting all the posts whose comment date is greater than todays datetime. I want to fetch post which are commented under 24 hours.

Can anybody help me in this. Any help would be appreciated..:)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take this . First one will give current datetime and second one will give 24 hours back time that is past day with the same time

```
echo $date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
echo '<br>';
echo $date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours', time()));
```

so you query should be like :

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT comment_post_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_date > '" . date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours', time())) . "'", OBJECT );
```